# Html2pdf (html2canvas + jsPdf) : how to set header with different margin from the text?

Tags: angular, html2pdf

I'm generating a PDF from a report using [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) (not the php one) with Angular 5. This report has a **image in the header** which it's supposed to be with **0 margin top, left, right, bottom**. 
And then i'd like to put the **text with a margin of 20 left, right and bottom** (for the top i don't know for now how it will react with the header).

I've tried several methods found on forums. In particular this [one](https://haensel.pro/allgemein/jspdf-html2pdf-loop-through-pages-and-add-content) which is not that old, but it is not doing anything.
The pdfCallback method doesn't seems to be used anymore in the current version of html2pdf.

So my question is, is there a way to do this ? Or else, i'm ready to take any other library/method that could help me to do so.

This is my current code which display everything but not with the right margins for the image in the header :

```
pdfOnClick() {
  let reportInHtml = 'myHtmlHeaderAndText';
        let opt = {
        margin: 20,
        enableLinks: true,
        filename: 'test.pdf',
        type: 'jpeg', quality: 1
      };
      html2pdf(reportInHtml, opt);
}
```

I just started to used html2pdf, few hours ago so i apologize if i'm missing something very basic. Every documentation/topics on internet i've found on the subject, are outdated and the documentation on the website is missing some examples (with all due respect). I'll be glad to add some, if i get an answer to my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to did it. It was a simple actually...Html2pdf can handle CSS. So if you set the margins in your html2pdf option to 0 (so that your header will be at 0 margins (top, right, left)  and set the margins from the style of your text to 15%(or whatever you desire) it works.